# Positioning sibling elements one over the other

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have a `TABLE` with multiple rows. Within each row one of the `TD` elements contains several `DIV` elements that:

1. can have any dimension but all of them (within one `TD`) have the same pixel dimension
2. have to be positioned one on top of the other
3. containing `TD` needs to resize according to child `DIV` elements
4. One `DIV` will be displayed at a time (statically)
5. when changing from one to the other fading will be used (so two of them will be displayed at the same time)
6. there will never be more than two of them displayed at the same time

This is a simplified example of such a table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>
            <div>First</div>
            <div>Second</div>
            ...
            <div>Last</div>
        </td>
        <td>Additionals</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>
            <div>First</div>
            <div>Second</div>
            ...
            <div>Last</div>
        </td>
        <td>Additionals</td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

The obvious solution would be to set

```
div
{
    position: absolute;
}
```

This will automatically position `DIV` elements on top of each other (according to flow layout), but `TD` dimension will stay as if it contains no child elements. Overflow doesn't do anything because child elements are absolutely positioned.

```
td
{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**How should I make this work?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know the size of the divs before hand? If so, you can just give a wrapper div those dimensions:

```
<td>
    <div class="wrapper">
       <div>1</div>
       <div>2</div>
       <div>3</div>
    etc...
```

If you don't won't know the size, then, since you are already using JS, you could grab the size of the first child div of wrapper and then set the wrapper dimensions via JS.

UPDATE:

The only way I can think of doing this with CSS all by itself would be to have the first DIV render twice. The first instance set to position: relative, and then it's duplicate, like the rest, can be set to position: absolute. This clone then acts like a shim. You could set visibility: hidden if you want to make sure it doesn't show up visually (but still takes up the proper space). The drawback to this, however, is that you now have content duplicated on your page, which may not be ideal from an SEO and/or accessibility POV.

I'd probably go the JS route and grab the dimensions after the page loads.

Comment: 1: No I don't know the size of my `div` elements on the server side so I could set container size. 2: I'm trying to avoid onReady scripts. But is there any other way than these two?

Comment: I accepted your answer. Your *duplicate* approach is the one I can actually use. But instead of having completely duplicate `div` I can render a simplified element that will have correct size but omit much of its sub HTML content. Thanks.